# Is broadcasting in Tensorflow a view or a copy?

Tags: tensorflow, array-broadcasting

Please clarify if broadcasting in Tensorflow will allocate a new memory buffer at broadcasting.

In the Tensorflow document [Introduction to Tensors - Broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor#broadcasting), one sentence says (emphasis added):

> Most of the time, broadcasting is both time and space efficient, as **the broadcast operation never materializes the expanded tensors in memory**

However in another sentence it says:

> Unlike a mathematical op, for example, broadcast_to does nothing special to save memory. Here, **you are materializing the tensor**.

```
print(tf.broadcast_to(tf.constant([1, 2, 3]), [3, 3]))
```

[tf.broadcast_to](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/broadcast_to) says it is a broadcast operation.

> Broadcast an array for a compatible shape.

Then according to "*the broadcast operation never materializes the expanded tensors in memory*" statement above, it should **not** be materializing.

Please help clarify what the document is actually saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says normally broadcast operation **never materializes** the expanded tensor in memory because of both time and space efficiency.

```
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
y = tf.constant(2)

print(x * y)
tf.Tensor([2 4 6], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

But if we want to look at how it looks after broadcasting then we use [`tf.broadcast_to`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/broadcast_to) which of course needs to materializing the tensor.

```
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = tf.broadcast_to(x, [3, 4])
print(y)

tf.Tensor(
[[1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]], shape=(3, 4), dtype=int32)
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/broadcast_to)

> When doing broadcasted operations such as multiplying a tensor by a scalar, broadcasting (usually) confers some time or space benefit, as the broadcasted tensor is **never materialized**.

> However, **broadcast_to does not carry with it any such benefits**. The newly-created tensor takes the full memory of the broadcasted shape. (In a graph context, broadcast_to might be fused to subsequent operation and then be optimized away, however.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still unsure what is occurring under the hood. When (x * y) is executed, x is rank 1 and y is rank 0, hence y is broadcast to rank 1 to match x. This broadcast may not need additional memory but how about the result (x * y)? I believe it is a new memory allocated and does not share memory buffer of x nor y. Then somewhere it needs to materialize (allocate buffer) to store (x*y), then it is materializing. If so how "never materialize" can be true... no sure.