# Pytorch Error: RuntimeError: output with shape [1, 3, 1] doesn't match the broadcast shape [3, 3, 7]

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to understand the reason this piece of code throws an error.

```
x=torch.empty(1,3,1)
y=torch.empty(3,1,7)
(x.add_(y)).size()
RuntimeError: output with shape [1, 3, 1] doesn't match the broadcast shape [3, 3, 7]
```

Reference: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#in-place-semantics

Based on the broadcasting rules, since every dimension has a one, the above tensor could have added to the second one to give a (3,3,7) tensor.

Numpy seems to perform the operation correctly producing a (3,3,7) tensor.

```
import numpy as np
x=np.empty((1,3,1))
y=np.empty((3,1,7))
(x + y).shape
Output: (3, 3, 7)
```

Could someone explain, why Pytorch produces an error, even though the rules are followed?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978119/is-broadcasting-in-tensorflow-a-view-or-a-copy

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem with the above code. So, the function add_() does x = x+y, which causes the problem, because there is a mismatch between x & y shape. Since, tensors are allocated as fixed memory sizes, doing the above operation should error out unless x has the same shape as the resulting tensor.